# Error: "Java-Bean. Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and that blank lines separate individual sections in both ..."

Tags: java, jar, meta-inf

I am trying to run a java jar file on a Windows 10 os in my bash terminal, and keep getting this error message:

> Duplicate name in Manifest: Java-Bean. Ensure that the manifest does
>   not have duplicate entries, and that blank lines separate individual
>   sections in both your manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry
>   in the jar file

I tried updating my java path variables, and looking for this META-INF folder, but I'm not sure where to find it.

Also, here is the command that I am entering:

```
java -jar ManualSentimentClassifier.jar train.csv test.csv positive.txt negative.txt
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I fixed this issue by opening the jar file archive (using 7zip).  I navigated to the META-INF folder and edited the MANIFEST.MF file and removed the duplicated Java Bean information.  After I did this, I no longer got the error